# How to fetch console.log data in jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to fetch console.log data in another function .we are getting value in console for example

```
triggerBtm: function(btmEvtObj){
         $(document).trigger(btmEvtObj);
        console.log(btmEvtObj);

    },
```

Need to fetch value of "btmEvtObj" in another function in separate file. I need to fetch value in another function placed in separate file.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, this isn't possible. You need to store the variable using cookies/sessions, a database, or external text file, or send it as a POST or Query String to the other page. Your only other option would be re-structuring your pages so that the function you want to use is accessible by the page you want to call it on.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just store that value in a variable.  All javascript variables declared outside of a scope are global, so they can be accessed from any function.

```
var eventObjectFromTrigger;
triggerBtm: function(btmEvtObj){
     $(document).trigger(btmEvtObj);
     eventObject = btmEvtObj;
},
```

Then in your other function (whether its a separate file or not), just access it...

```
function foo(){
    $(eventObjectFromTrigger).doSomething();
}
```

Comment: `All javascript variables are global` ... `function test() { var x = 5; } console.log(x)` might cause some problems.

Answer (score 0):

by the syntax it looks like triggerBtm is a method contained by another object. Add a `return` to the method body and access it in another file by calling the method from the object.

File 1

```
var yourObject = {
    triggerBtm: function(btmEvtObj){
        $(document).trigger(btmEvtObj);
        console.log(btmEvtObj);
        return btmEvtObj;
    },
};
```

File 2

```
var yourValue = yourObject.triggerBtm();
```

Comment: We cannot make changes in file1 as code is freeze, we only have console.log to fetch the data and work on file2

Comment: @RuchitaMhatre Unfortunately, you cannot retrieve data from the console.

Answer (score 0):

Try Replacing The Whole Console with user-defined function:

```
var console = {log: function(data){
    $("#console-1").append(JSON.stringify(data)+"\n");
},
error: function(data){
    $("#console-1").append(JSON.stringify(data)+"\n");
},
warn: function(data){
    $("#console-1").append(JSON.stringify(data)+"\n");
}};
```

This example will append all console log data in div#console-1.